# Same page names. Namespaces? Aliases? Hierarchy?

Tags: mediawiki

My wiki page has many pages that have the same name. I have no idea how to avoid name clashes.

For example:

```
softwareA->topicA
softwareB->topicA
softwareC->topicA
softwareC->topicC->topicA
```

How can I manage this?  Should I create namespaces for each sofware? I read its not a good idea...
But it's a pretty good idea in the programming world. In fact, I wish I had:

namespace softwareA
namespace softwareB...

softwareA.topicA
softwareB.topicA

both pages would have the same name. Their URL address should be different. But I see all pages I create are inside the root, so obviously it's impossible.

Sometimes I also have to add words after the page name to diferentiate. Example:

```
folders (windows)

folders (images, windows)
```

How does people organize stuff like this?

Comment: Namespaces are mostly static, your list if software is probably not. They are mainly meant for supporting different functionality for different "areas" of the site (access control for example). Not a good match for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if [subpages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Subpages) would work for you or not, but you can [enable  them for the main namespace](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNamespacesWithSubpages#Enabling-for-a-namespace) on your wiki. Using this feature you could create a page named `softwareA/topicA` and another `softwareA/topicB`, and link to them from `softwareA`... I won't go into the details, the MediaWiki manual seems fairly comprehensive.

Depending on your needs, it might also be a good idea to [categorize](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories) those subpages.

Comment: You could augment it with [breadcrumbs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BreadCrumbs2) and [displaytitle](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#DISPLAYTITLE) for a nicer look.

Comment: @Tgr About breadcrumbs, it's nice! But I'm really worried about using plugins ... when they stop working.... It leaves all my wiki pages broken. Display title... I forgot about it. Thanks!

Comment: Subpages... mmm. Ok. I'll have a look. But everything in my wiki is categorized of course. The problem is that pages inside different categories will have the same name....